# Node unhandled promise rejections with require

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

Simplified code:

// File A

```
module.exports = new Promise((res, rej) => {

  ... do stuff

  if (someErr) {
   return rej(someErr);
  }

  return res(stuff)
}
```

// File B

```
const fileA = require('./fileA');

... express stuff

app.get('/getA', (req, res) => {
  fileA
    .then(data => res.send(data))
    .catch(e => res.send(404, e));
  });
```

As you can see the promise rejection gets caught when running a post request to a route in `file B`. This way it is also possible to send a 404 response with the original error trough.

The problem is, there is an ***Unhandled Promise Rejection*** from `file A` whenever the route is called. VERY annoying.

> (node:5040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>
> (node:5040) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Yes, sure, i could catch the rejection in `file A`, but i would rather prefer it propagate upstream and catch it later.

Comment: Just do `fileA.catch(err => console.debug("A will not be available (404) because "+err));` in the second file to handle the rejection immediately. You can still chain other handlers to the promise for answering requests. If you don't want a log message, write `fileA.catch(err => { /* ignore */ });` (with a comment about where it will be handled later).

Answer (score 0):

With the way you structured your code, the rejection is thrown before the `.catch` is attached to the promise, so technically, it's was unhandled *at the moment it was thrown*.

I'm sure you have a reason why you would want to structure it like that (perhaps run *"do stuff"* only once?), so a possible workaround would be this:

```
// File A
let promise = null;
module.exports = () => {
  if (! promise) {
    promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {

      ... do stuff

      if (someErr) {
        return rej(someErr);
      }

      return res(stuff)
    });
  }
  return promise;
};

// File B
app.get('/getA', (req, res) => {
  fileA()
    .then(data => res.send(data))
    .catch(e => res.send(404, e));
});
```